# awk or sed - delete specific lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've got this

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
```

I want this

```
line1
line3
line5
line6
line8
line10
line11
line13
line15
```

As you can see , the line to be deleted are going from x+2 then x+3 , x equals the line number to be deleted.

I tried this with awk but this is not the right way.

```
awk '(NR)%2||(NR)%3' file > filev1
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: hi @anubhava , the lines that should be deleted are line2, 4 , 7 ,9 , 12 ,  15 etc ...

Comment: Should it not be: `2,4,7,9,12,14` ?

Comment: indeed it is 2,4,7,9,12,14. Sorry @anubhava -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I decipher your requirements correctly, then

```
awk 'NR % 5 != 2 && NR % 5 != 4' file
```

should do.

Comment: Nice! I like @Jotne's tweak too `awk 'NR%5!~/^[24]$/' file` since it removes the redundancy of calculating `NR%5` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Wintermutes logic :)

```
awk 'NR%5!~/^[24]$/' file
line1
line3
line5
line6
line8
line10
line11
line13
line15
```

or

```
awk 'NR%5~/^[013]$/' file
```

---

How it works.

We can see from your lines that the one with `*` should be removed and other kept.

```
line1
line2*
line3
line4*
line5

line6
line7*
line8
line9*
line10

line11
line12*
line13
line14*
line15
```

By grouping data inn to every `5` line `NR%5`, 
We see that line to delete is `2` or `4` in every group.
`NR%5!~/^[24]$/'` This divide data inn to group of `5` 
Then this part `/^[24]$/'` tell to not keep `2` or `4`
The `^` and `$` is important so line `12` `47` i deleted too,
since `12` contains `2`.  So we need to anchor it `^2$` and `^4$`.

Comment: Hi @Jotne, can you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: What is it for `^[013]$` ?

Comment: @AndyK see my update.  This `^[013]$` gives number  `0` or `1` or `3`

Comment: alleluia @jotne ! I understood something that was eluding me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed, you can do the following command:

```
 sed '2~5d;4~5d' test.txt
```